# Huge Scale Scenes in Blender

Tags: 3d, rendering, blender

Is there any way to model very large scenes in Blender? I'm unable to find a way to work with something actually sized to 1 mile. This is for an animation that would include flyovers of fields, along highways etc. so there has to be a sense of great depth to everything. How can I do this without either making something insanely large or having the vertices way too close together?

Answer (score 2):

To help with modelling to a real world size you can enable units, to help with large models you can increase the scale.

[image] [image]

With large models the camera clipping settings need to be considered. For the 3dview you can change this in the view panel of the properties sidebar <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

For the camera you may also need to change clipping and focal length to get the right look.

[image]

For a large scene you don't need to get carried away with detail. When the ground is 100 feet away you don't see each grain of sand. A house can be 10 verts and a image texture and still look the same as a 1000 vert house. Mountains in the distance can be images on a plane.

You also might find that you don't need to make it really big to make it look big. Have a look at [sintel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRsGyueVLvQ) or [this mountain flyover](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbzWkHQdgKo) or [this winter gazebo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KKLJg509_A) which I believe is based off the scene you can [download from here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249664-UPDATED-bend-19-Billions-of-Polygons-not-a-ridiculous-number-anymore), I'm not certain of the winter gazebo video but the other three don't make use of units or scaling to make everything big.

You can also find more blender focused help at [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)